# C Password Log giving me errors

Tags: c, passwords, c-strings

C password functions not working. I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone help?

`Error: Incomplete universal character \u`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

void userLog(int attempt, char user_name[], char user_pass[]);
void checkUserLog(int attempt, char user_name[], char user_pass[]);

int main()
{
    system("color 1F"); //change UI background to blue and text to white

    int *pos = 0;
    int attempt = 0;
    int low, high, *temp_pos;
    char searchKey[50], *is_found[200];
    char user_name[6], user_pass[12];

    //printf("print main's test\n\n");

    userLog(attempt, user_name, user_pass);
    //libraryBookMainMenu(searchKey[50], low, high, &is_found[200], &temp_pos);
    //systemMainMenu();

    fflush(stdin);
    getch();
}


void userLog(int attempt, char user_name[], char user_pass[])
{
   system("cls");
   if (attempt == 0) {
      printf("Access is Denied!!!");
      Sleep(1500);
      attempt = 3; //done to reset attempts for user login
      exit(2);
   }
   attempt--;

   printf("\n\n Enter your username: ");
   fflush(stdin);  // done to clear last input after the while statement is not true
   scanf("%s", &user_name);
   printf("\n\n Enter your password: ");
   fflush(stdin);  // done to clear last input after the while statement is not true
   checkUserLog(attempt, user_name, user_pass);
}


void checkUserLog(int attempt, char user_name[], char user_pass[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char get_char;
    char default_user[] = "admin";
    char default_pass[] = "adminpass00";

    while (i < 10) {
        get_char = getch();
        if (get_char == 13) {
            break;  //ASCII value for enter
        }
        if (get_char == 8) {
            putch('\b');  //escape sequence for backspace
            putch(' ');  //puts an empty space as you backspace
            putch('\b');  //return blinking cursor to original position
            i--;
            continue;  //without this backspace won't work
        }
        user_pass[i] = get_char;
        printf("*");
        i++;
    }

    user_pass[i] = '\0';

    /*while (strcmp(user_name,default_user)!= 0 || strcmp(user_pass,default_pass) != 0) {
         printf("\n Incorrect password\username\n\n\t %d more attempts remaining", attempt);
         Sleep(1500);
         userLog(attempt, user_name, user_pass);
    }*/

    attempt = 3;
    //libraryBookMainMenu(bookLibrary, searchKey[50], low, high, &pos, &temp_pos);
}
```

Comment: The error message obviously has nothing to do with passwd functions, so why does your question? And post the code that actually fails -- this doesn't, as you've commented out the erroneous code -- and include the line number in the error message and/or mark the offending line clearly in the code you post.

Answer (score 0):

`\u` is a special code in `printf`; your code contains `\username` which is causing the error you are getting. I suspect you just have a typo there; if not, represent a backslash in `printf` with `\\`.

Per @Jim Balter's comment, you probably used `\` where you meant `/`.

Comment: The OP wants a forward slash -- "Incorrect password/username"